# Tell `dotnet build` to also compile source files in a subfolder

Tags: c#, compilation, .net-core, subdirectory

I'm going to preface this by saying I'm not only new to the .NET Core, but I'm new to C# as well, though this isn't a code problem. Anyway, my project is laid out like this:

[image: Visual Studio Solution Explorer Screenshot]

All I'm trying to find out, is how I can get `dotnet build` to also compile the files in the Items folder. I ran `dotnet build --help` but didn't find anything that seemed to help, so I assume I'll have to do something with the .csproj file. But either way, how can I accomplish this?

EDIT:

The accepted answer is correct, though my problem ended up being that I needed to add a `using HouseCS.Items;` line. (New to Namespaces...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making classes public should get you your desired result.

Comment: They are, I get errors like this:
`House.cs(73,30): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Item' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`
And Item.cs looks like this: has `namespace HouseCS.Items` and `public interface Item`

Looking at this closer though, I may have goofed. I don't think the problem is the files, I think there actually is a code error :p. I'll investigate, and update my post accordingly.